Graph API file upload itemNotFound
We have a conversion to upload all the attachments to sharepoint, this conversions runs in multiple threads and can take a while since we could have lots of attachments.
A customer tried this conversions and during the 6 hours it suddenly started giving error namely:

Error calling Graph API endpoint /drives/<drive_id>/items/:/Calculations/2020-09/20-05039 [74779]/19-00919.lnk:/content
{"error":{"code":"itemNotFound","message":"Item not found","innerError":{"date":"2024-04-23T09:09:47","request-id":"eab0bbcf-769f-43e0-9397-adbe84a93ba3","client-request-id":"eab0bbcf-769f-43e0-9397-adbe84a93ba3"}}}

It tries to upload a shortcut file to sharepoint, these shortcut files are created and put into the temp folder of the machine to be uploaded from. And before uploading to sharepoint a check is done to see if the file exists. So right before it will upload the file, it should still exists, so I don't really get why we are getting this error message.
I also can't seem to reproduce this in my local system.
